Nextjs hydration error on kinde auth version
I already used auth from kinde. Firstly I check user login auth, so I take the condition for when the user is login in our system I show the logout button UI to the page. When the user is not able to login I show the register vs login button UI to the page. But I got the hydration error when I run the code. IDK. what cause this error is happened. what wrong?
I'm really stuck on this error. Please help.

// components/UserNav.tsx
'use client';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Image from "next/image";
import default_user from "../public/plain_user.webp";
import { MenuIcon } from "lucide-react";
import { getKindeServerSession } from "@kinde-oss/kinde-auth-nextjs/server";
import {
  RegisterLink,
  LoginLink,
  LogoutLink,
} from "@kinde-oss/kinde-auth-nextjs/components";
import {
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownMenuTrigger,
  DropdownMenuContent,
  DropdownMenuItem,
} from "./ui/dropdown-menu";

const UserNav: React.FC = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<string | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUser = async () => {
      const { getUser } = getKindeServerSession();
      const userData = await getUser();
      console.log(userData)
    };

    fetchUser();
  }, []);

  return (
    <DropdownMenu>
      <DropdownMenuTrigger>
        <div className="rounded-full border px-2 py-2 lg:px-4 lg:py-2 flex items-center gap-x-3">
          <MenuIcon className="w-6 h-6 lg:w-5 lg:h-5" />
          <Image
            src={default_user}
            alt="user"
            className="rounded-full w-8 h-8 hidden lg:block"
          />
        </div>
      </DropdownMenuTrigger>
      <DropdownMenuContent align="end" className="w-[200px]">
        {user ? (
          <>
            <DropdownMenuItem>
              <LogoutLink className="w-full">Logout</LogoutLink>
            </DropdownMenuItem>
          </>
        ) : (
          <>
            <DropdownMenuItem>
              <RegisterLink className="w-full">Register</RegisterLink>
            </DropdownMenuItem>
            <DropdownMenuItem>
              <LoginLink className="w-full">Login</LoginLink>
            </DropdownMenuItem>
          </>
        )}
      </DropdownMenuContent>
    </DropdownMenu>
  );
};

export default UserNav;


are you using chakra-ui ? if yes, then, chakra-ui some problem with hydration

No. I used shadcn UI. if you know solution please help. I'm really stuck

Can you create a repository on codesandbox? So I easily figure out what's going on in the code, because until I didn't know about the dropMenu or other shadcn ui i can't help you out

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
